# onclick, how can I hide a <div> and show the content behind it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this `<div>` hide itself when a click occurs outside of it? I would like to be able to hide it and then show the rest of the content of the page that is behind it.

```
<html>
<style>
.overlay
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 80;
}
.popupContent
{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 400px;
    bottom: 365px;
    right: 300px;
    z-index: 81;
}​

</style>

<div id="initialPopup">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="popupContent" onclick="hideInitialPopup()">
    Good Morning, Please Upload Your File Today!
    </div>

</div>
 ​



<script>
function hideInitialPopup() {
    document.getElementById("initialPopup").style.display = "block";
    $("popupContent").mouseup(function(){
    if(! mouse_is_inside) $
}​
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's `event.target` to determine if you've clicked within the box or not:

```
 $(document).on('click',function(e) {
     if (!$(e.target).closest('#my_div_id').length) {
         $('#my_div_id').hide();
     } 
 });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/PNYTX/

Comment: Change 'my_div_id' to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: what should i put there so when i click outside my div box popupContent ?? i can go back to my website content

Comment: you can see my code above is it correct because it isn't working :( ?

Comment: Use my code as a replacement for the JavaScript currently between your `<script>` tags. Change `my_div_id` to 'initialPopup' or whatever you need it to be. Make sure you've loaded jQuery before running this code by adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your own `<script>`. For more help, please visit http://jquery.com and familiarize yourself with the basics.

Comment: thank you so much for your help below is what i have so far but it isn't working may you please help me some more?


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
 $(document).on('click',function(e) {
     if (!$(e.target).closest('#my_div_id').length) {
         $('#initialPopup').hide();
     } 
 });
</script>

Comment: i actually have both changed to #initialPopup

Comment: Please visit http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works and learn the basics of how to use it in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you use a mask with something like a popup/dialog, it's easiest just to attach a click handler to the mask itself that hides the popup/dialog when clicked.

Here is a jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/peterdev001/SDNUj/